# Android app not running on the device

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I tried building an app to record video using `MediaPlayer` using code from android.developers website. But when I open it in my device, it says that unfortunately the app needs to close. But when I run it on the Emulator, I can see that it works (using the logs). Here is the `MainActivity` code.

```
package com.example.camcorder_mediaplayer;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.media.CamcorderProfile;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
        SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    MediaRecorder recorder;
    SurfaceHolder holder;
    boolean recording = false;
    public static final String TAG = "VIDEOCAPTURE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        initrecorder();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SurfaceView cameraView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.CameraView);
        holder = cameraView.getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        cameraView.setClickable(true);
        cameraView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void initrecorder() {
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
        recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
        CamcorderProfile cpHig = CamcorderProfile
                .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
        recorder.setProfile(cpHigh);
        recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/videocapture_example.mp4");
        recorder.setMaxDuration(50000);
        recorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000);
    }

    private void prepareRecorder() {
        recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
        try {
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            finish();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0,int arg1,int arg2,int arg3){}

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Surface Created");
        prepareRecorder();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Surface deleed");
        if (recording) {
            recorder.stop();
            recording = false;
        }
        recorder.release();
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if (recording) {
            recorder.stop();
            recording = false;
            // recorder.release()
            Log.v(TAG, "Recording stopped");
            initrecorder();
            prepareRecorder();
        } else {
            recording = true;
            recorder.start();
            Log.v(TAG, "Recording started");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, post relevant logcat stacktrace

Comment: Please send us your logcat, moreover the part related to the crash.

Comment: Logcat will be very helpful